# {Python} - [Pandas] - How sum columns by condition less than in columns name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

First explaining the dataframe, the values of columns '0-156', '156-234', '234-546' .... '> 76830' is the percentage distribution for each range of distances in meters, totaling 100%.
Column 'Cell Name' refers to the data element of the other columns and the column 'Distance' is the column that will trigger the desired sum.

I need to sum the values of the columns '0-156', '156-234', '234-546' .... '> 76830' which are less than the value of the 'Distance' (Meters) column.

Below creation code for testing.

```
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['Test1',0.36516562,19.065996,49.15094,24.344206,0.49186087,1.24217,5.2812457,0.05841639,0,0,0,0,158.4122868],
['Test2',0.20406325,10.664485,48.70978,14.885571,0.46103176,8.75815,14.200708,2.1162114,0,0,0,0,192.553074],
['Test3',0.13483211,0.6521175,6.124511,41.61725,45.0036,5.405257,1.0494527,0.012979688,0,0,0,0,1759.480042]
]  

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Cell Name','0-156','156-234','234-546','546-1014','1014-1950','1950-3510','3510-6630','6630-14430','14430-30030','30030-53430','53430-76830','>76830','Distance'])
```

Example of what should be done:
    The value of column 'Distance' = 158.412286772863 therefore would have to sum the values <= of the following columns, 0-156, '156-234' totalizing 19.43116162 %.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to sum up all the percentage values in a row, where the lower value of the column-description (in case of '0-156' it would be 0, in case of '156-234' it would be 156, and so on...) is smaller than the value in the distance column.
First I would suggest, that you transform your string-like column-names into values, as an example:

```
lowerlimit=df.columns[2]
>>'156-234'
```

Then read the string only till the '-' and make it a number

```
int(lowerlimit[:lowerlimit.find('-')])
>> 156
```

You can loop this through all your columns and make a new row for the lower limits.

For a bit more simplicity I left out the first column for your example, and added another first row with the lower limits of each column, that you could generate as described above. Then this code works:

```
data = [[0,156,234,546,1014,1950,3510,6630,11430,30030,53430,76830,1e-23],[0.36516562,19.065996,49.15094,24.344206,0.49186087,1.24217,5.2812457,0.05841639,0,0,0,0,158.4122868],
[0.20406325,10.664485,48.70978,14.885571,0.46103176,8.75815,14.200708,2.1162114,0,0,0,0,192.553074],
[0.13483211,0.6521175,6.124511,41.61725,45.0036,5.405257,1.0494527,0.012979688,0,0,0,0,1759.480042]
]  

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['0-156','156-234','234-546','546-1014','1014-1950','1950-3510','3510-6630','6630-14430','14430-30030','30030-53430','53430-76830','76830-','Distance'])
df['lastindex']=None
df['sum']=None
```

After creating basically your dataframe, I add two columns 'lastindex' and 'sum'.

Then I am searching for the last index in every row, that is has its lower limit below the distance given in that row (df.iloc[x,-3]); afterwards I'm summing up the respective columns in that row.

```
for i in np.arange(1,len(df)):
    df.at[i,'lastindex']=np.where(df.iloc[0,:-3]<df.iloc[i,-3])[0][-1]
    df.at[i,'sum']=sum(df.iloc[i][0:df.at[i,'lastindex']+1])
```

I hope, this is helpful. Best, lepakk